# heatmap not rendering in grafana, no heatmap fields found

Tags: grafana

I am trying to do a heatmap in grafana to show some performance data coming from a game engine

the data is stored in postgreSQL I m extracting build_version and frame_time, I would love to display in a heatmap , build_version would be displayed in the Y axis, and on x axis frame_time, splitted by 10 milliseconds cells, inside the cell I want a color representing the value in % to be able to display how the values are distributed. by selecting differents build_version from the variables, I will be able to compare performance between version.

My date is properly displayed if I selected table view, I see a table with 2 rows build_version. frame_time , but in heatmap mode I get "no heatmap fields found" and I m struggling finding what to configure to get this done ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand data format you want to visualize correctly (some demo example of data would certainly help), but from what I understood it feels that something like simply Time series graph with two lines will be more suited. I believe heatmap expects Y axis to be represented by buckets of some numeric value.

Comment: something like this https://apexcharts.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/heatmap-color-range.png with build version at y axis, and inside the cell a color or number representing the number of values inside the cell. I tried other representation and will try your suggestion